# How to disable a MS Fabric checkbox when already one is selected in a group

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, office-ui-fabric

I am using MS-Fabric checkbox component and I want to uncheck a checkbox when another is selected.
Cant use radio as this is not a mandatory field.

Half Day Booking 
                                            
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                            Full Day Booking

Comment: Why not use it as when checked it's a half-day, when unchecked it's a full day booking

Comment: Are there only two options?

Answer (score 0):

My test code for your reference:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import styles from './OfficeUispfx.module.scss';
    import { IOfficeUispfxProps } from './IOfficeUispfxProps';
    import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
    import { Checkbox } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Checkbox';
    export default class OfficeUispfx extends React.Component<IOfficeUispfxProps, any> {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          checked:Boolean
        };
        this._onChange=this._onChange.bind(this)
      }
      public render(): React.ReactElement<IOfficeUispfxProps> {
        return (
          <div className={ styles.officeUispfx }>
            <div className={ styles.container }>
              <div className={ styles.row }>
                <div className={ styles.column }>
                  <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
                  <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
                  <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
                  <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                    <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <Checkbox label="Half Day Booking" onChange={this._onChange} checked={this.state.checked}/>
                <Checkbox label="Full Day Booking" onChange={this._onChange} checked={!this.state.checked}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
       _onChange(ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>, isChecked: boolean) {
         console.log(ev)
         let checked=this.state.checked
           
          this.setState({
            checked:!checked
          })
         
      }
    }
```

Test result:
[image]